# Anatomically Correct Frieza

Tags: science-based, creature-design, evolution, aliens

This is a submission for the [Anatomically Correct Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series/2798#2798)

Frieza is a super villain in the Dragon Ball series that looks like a small biped humanoid with thick smooth pale white skin, a chestnut shaped head , three toes , a long strong tail and lizard-like earholes with bright red eyes.

Given the characteristics what evolutionary pressures could lead to the rise of such a being?

[image]

Comment: Does this have to factor in how apparently most of his internal systems are redundant? Such as how being sliced in half barely inconveniences him aside from mobility?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: This is a question about a commercial / third party intellectual property. It should be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**He is a human with prosthetics.**

The evolutionary pressures are the same ones as we have, because he is human.  This is given away by his musculature in the legs and torso, which are those of a human and not of something which would use legs for climbing or require the counterbalance of a large saurian tail to walk.

He has swapped out his feet for smart prosthetics that allow him to use his toes more dexterously.  His hands are prosthetics too but he is currently wearing ones that are much like his original hands.  The headpiece is an overlay which is given away by the obviously artificial ear holes.

The tail is mobile, but artificial and hollow - more of an affectation than anything else.  You can tell it is hollow because if it were muscle he would be leaning forward to balance.  He is smirking because the presence of this tail tells persons in the know about certain preferences this individual has, and he thinks you are one of those persons.